# how to set value in text box on button click on other page in uwp?

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, win-universal-app, uwp, uwp-xaml

In My page right side have some text box (page 1) and in left side some button like 1,2,3(page 2)  on text box got focus page 2 come out in frame.
now My problem is that how to set value in text box which is in page 1 on button click which is on page 2 in uwp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [FrameworkElement.FindName method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.findname.aspx) to get the `TextBox` in your page 1 from your page 2.

For example here:
MainPage has two `Frame`:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Frame x:Name="frame1"></Frame>
    <Frame x:Name="frame2" Grid.Column="1"></Frame>
</Grid>
```

code behind:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.frame1.Navigate(typeof(MenuPage));
    this.frame2.Navigate(typeof(Page1));
}
```

`MenuPage` is a blank page here in my test.

Page 1:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Tapped="Grid_Tapped">
    <TextBlock Name="textBlock" Text="This is Page 1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="25" />
    <Button VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1"></Button>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBox Name="tb1" GotFocus="tb_GotFocus" />
        <TextBox Name="tb2" Margin="0,30" GotFocus="tb_GotFocus" />
        <TextBox Name="tb3" GotFocus="tb_GotFocus" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

code behind:

```cs
public Page1()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += Page1_Loaded;
}

private Frame frame;

private void Page1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    Page mainPage = rootFrame.Content as MainPage;
    frame = mainPage.FindName("frame1") as Frame;
}

private void tb_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
}

private void Grid_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (frame.CanGoBack)
        frame.GoBack();
}
```

Page 2:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Text="This is Page 2" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="25" />
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="Button 1" Click="Button_Click_1" />
        <Button Content="Button 2" Click="Button_Click_2" Margin="0,30" />
        <Button Content="Button 3" Click="Button_Click_3" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

code behind:

```cs
public Page2()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += Page2_Loaded;
}

private TextBox tb1;
private TextBox tb2;
private TextBox tb3;

private void Page2_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    Page mainPage = rootFrame.Content as MainPage;
    Frame frame = mainPage.FindName("frame2") as Frame;
    Page page1 = frame.Content as Page1;
    tb1 = page1.FindName("tb1") as TextBox;
    tb2 = page1.FindName("tb2") as TextBox;
    tb3 = page1.FindName("tb3") as TextBox;
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tb1.Text = "Button 1 Clicked!";
}

private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tb2.Text = "Button 2 Clicked!";
}

private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tb3.Text = "Button 3 Clicked!";
}
```

Rendering Image:
[image]

**Update**:
MainPage calls Page 1:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Content="Navigate to Page 1" Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
```

code behind:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page1));
}
```

Page 1 has a Frame and calls Page 2:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Frame Name="myframe"></Frame>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Name="textBlock" Text="This is Page 1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="25" />
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1"></Button>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBox Name="tb1" GotFocus="tb_GotFocus" />
            <TextBox Name="tb2" Margin="0,30" GotFocus="tb_GotFocus" />
            <TextBox Name="tb3" GotFocus="tb_GotFocus" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

code behind:

```cs
private void tb_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myframe.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
}
```

Page 2:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Text="This is Page 2" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="25" />
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="Button 1" Click="Button_Click_1" />
        <Button Content="Button 2" Click="Button_Click_2" Margin="0,30" />
        <Button Content="Button 3" Click="Button_Click_3" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

code behind is a little different:

```cs
public Page2()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += Page2_Loaded;
}

private TextBox tb1;
private TextBox tb2;
private TextBox tb3;

private void Page2_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    Page page1 = rootFrame.Content as Page1;
    tb1 = page1.FindName("tb1") as TextBox;
    tb2 = page1.FindName("tb2") as TextBox;
    tb3 = page1.FindName("tb3") as TextBox;
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tb1.Text = "Button 1 Clicked!";
}

private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tb2.Text = "Button 2 Clicked!";
}

private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tb3.Text = "Button 3 Clicked!";
}
```

Comment: I have Only one frame in mainpage and that calls the page1(textbox). In page1 i have another frame which calls page2 having button 1, button 2 .plz tell me how to write page1 code with page 2 code.

Comment: @TrishitBera, OK, please see the Update part of my answer. It's much easier, but the key point is still using `FindName` to get the control, just the `Content` of the `rootFrame` is different here.

Comment: Page page1 = rootFrame.Content as Page1; page1 shows null after thats errors come 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'. plz tell if  something missing.

Comment: @TrishitBera, Did you test my sample or changed my sample to yours? It's the problem with the `Content` of the `rootFrame`, as you can see that I navigated from MainPage to Page1, the frame of these two pages are all rootFrame here, but if you set a frame control in the MainPage and navigate in this frame to Page 1, you should at first find MainPage, then find this frame, then find Page1.

Comment: Its solve my Big Problem..Thank you Very much... salute to you sir..  :)

Comment: I am facing another problem on same scenario. now page1 have 3 texboxes and page2 have 2 button, when textbox1 got focus then whatever button click on page2 then letters should write on texbox1 . if textbox2 got focus then whatever button click on page2 then letters should write on texbox2. how should i detect which textbox get focus from page 2.

Comment: @TrishitBera, Can you open a new question? we discussed too much in the comment. It's easy, when you call page 2, just navigate with parameter.  For example: `myframe.Navigate(typeof(Page2), "TextBox1GotFocus");`

Comment: Thank you For Reply...No i am not open new Question..you already solve my big problem..... Yesterday i done the same solution... but I think that  you have some other better solution.. thats why asking the Question.. Thank You again Solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found. It was a combination of part of above. The ShellPage was a frame page. It had a textblock and this code was in the app.xaml.cs page.

```
ShellPage currentPage = Window.Current.Content as ShellPage;
TextBlock tb1 = currentPage.FindName("InternetConnection") as TextBlock;
tb1.Text = InternetConnectionText;
tb1.Foreground = InternetConnectionForeground;
```